# IIS starting Issue"Process W3SVC can't be started on this computer . " - cant remove Windows components?

Tags: iis, windows-services, w3c

I have some strange behaviour trying to starting my IIS 10.

> **infos about services:**
>   W3C Protokollierungsdienst -> runs, stops after a while
>   WWW Publishingservice -> cant be started (see screenshot)
>   [wwwservicefailscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TJ0V.png)
>   Windows Acitvation Service -> cant be started (see screenshot)
>   [wasservicefailscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHGcG.png)

on IIS i get the following error if i try to start it:
[iisstartingscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eePy7.png)

i have tried to uninstall all the relevant IIS components over the Windows Feature Panel.
uninstalled it, restared the system, checked the Windows features and component panel, **all packages still installed**

so here is my issue about, i seems that my stem does not really remove the IIS or WAS Service component.

### UPDATE

so i installed the patches from August 2018.
but nothing changed - i manually installed kb4343909 - but it did not resolve my issue.
i also tried some of the patches which are in the thread (link from @Lex Li) but i did not help either.
what can i try furthermore? i'm really stuck on this and have to finish my project...
do i really have to rollback all the updates before july? i think its time to swith to linux or so... i'm really disappointed about MS...

Comment: You missed the party.

Please refer to posts to learn what Microsoft July Windows patches caused the problem and then resolve it.

https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches

Comment: @LexLi thank you for sharing this link. i already guessed that it has to be some buggy Update from MS.
But - i'm facing this Issue on my Windows 10 machine - not windows Server. can i use the fixes anyway?

Comment: The bad updates affect all Windows releases, not only Windows Server.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for your confirmation.
i found out that it should be this Update for Win10: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345421/windows-10-update-kb4345421
but it seems it does not fit to my OS version.
but it seems this should be it...

Comment: also tried it with http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4345418
but i get the same message "package not valid for this system"

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/iis-wont-start-after-upgrade-to-1803-was-fails/0546e24f-6573-4445-b8d5-d17096a5fcfc

in the comments there was a "hack" which actualy worked on my windows 10 64bit machine:

> Just delete the registry entry "NanoSetup" with running cmd command.
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WAS\Parameters" /v NanoSetup /f 
>   Now you can start the service again.