# IIS not working after Windows security patch updates

Tags: windows, iis, .net-framework-version

We have our WebSite hosted on IIS on windows server machines.
The recent windows security patch updates has caused some issues in accessing Web Application.

Only after removing the patches, cleared the issue.
Did anyone faced such issues..

Please share your thoughts..

Below is the problem reported (in their words)by our customer support team..

"After installing the below updates, both sites started experiencing issues"
KB4096417
KB4095875
KB4093753

Site-1 experienced slow web login and finally upon reaching the playback screen x minutes later, it was blank. Re-rolling server back to previous point resolved this issue.

Site-2 experienced issues during Engage fresh install. Installer Brian Snyder uninstalled updates and was finally able to install **** afterwards.

Here are 2 more reported instances

Windows updates Cases
Case 1: 
Problem – Recording stopped/ Can’t play any calls.
Cause – Windows Updates
Solution – Remove Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 (KB4338606), rebooting server after clearing this patch  cleared the issue.

Case 2:
Problem – IIS not working (Web not accessible)
Cause – Windows Updates
Solution – Removed, no reboot needed. They removed all 4 at once.

Removed following KBs to recover [KB4338824, KB4338815, KB4340006, KB4339093].

Comment: Most people knew this in July, so you are late to the party too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748005/iis-starting-issueprocess-w3svc-cant-be-started-on-this-computer-cant-re Microsoft published further information on all problematic patches, and if you don't fully understand their texts, talk to their support team by opening a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks @ Lex Li, will checkout the link you shared.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li, the shared link was helpful.